# Let $f(x)=[1]x\in\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$. Find a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x)=[1]x\in\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$. Find a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ such that $p(x)\ne f(x)$, but $p\colon \mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}_6$ defines the same function as $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}_6$.

I am not sure what he is asking..? Expecially, $p\colon \mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}_6$ defines the same function as $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}_6$. this part makes me confused

Comment: A polynomial might not be the identity polynomial, but define the identity function on a given ring. I think the problem asks you to find a polynomial $p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ that is not equal to $x$, but fulfills $p(a) = a$ for all elements $a$ of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: What does $[1]$ mean?

Comment: @StefanGyürki: I think [1] should be the class of 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. I would just write $x$ instead of $[1]x$.

Comment: @user44400: I have the same guess..

Answer (score 0):

Different polynomials in $\mathbb Z_m[X]$ can define the same function $\mathbb Z_m \to \mathbb Z_m$.

Fermat's theorem tells us that for $p$ a prime, the polynomial $x^{p}-x$ induces the zero function even though it is not the zero polynomial.

*Hint:* Try to find a non-zero polynomial $g$ such that $g(a)=0$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z_6$. Then take $p=f+g$.

Although $6$ is not a prime, look anyway for $g(x)=x^{n}-x$, for some $n$.

Solution:

> $g(x)=x^3-x$ works. So does $g(x)=x^n-x$ with $n$ odd.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164524/largest-modulus-for-fermat-type-polynomial.