# How do I show that $2730$ divides $n^{13}-n$ for $n$ is integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have tried to show that : $2730 |$ $n^{13}-n$ using fermat little theorem but i can't succeed or at a least to write $2730$ as $n^p-n$  .

**My question here** : How do I show that $2730$ divides $n^{13}-n$ for $n$ is integer ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: $2730=2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 13$ and apply Little Fermat to each prime factor

Comment: Then of course Chinese Remainder theorem...

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164524/largest-modulus-for-fermat-type-polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use Fermat's Theorem, working separately modulo $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, and $13$.  (Note that $2730=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 13$.)

Answer (score 1):

First you calculate the prime factorisation of $2730$. You will find that it splits in 5 prime factors. Then use the Chinese Remainder theorem and show that $n^{13}\equiv n \pmod{p}$ for the prime factors.

Comment: What if n is greater than p?

Comment: You can use Fermat's little theorem. It does not matter if $n$ is greater than $p$.