# Divisors of a polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started reading a book about number theory, and in one of the excersises I needed to prove that $30|n^5-n$ for any $n$. Using the division algorithm I managed to show that $2|n^5-n$, $3|n^5-n$ and that $5|n^5-n$, and so $30|n^5-n$ as requested.

The prove for $5|n^5-n$ (which is the most complex) went as follows:
$$n = 5q + r \Rightarrow n^5 = (5q + r)^5 \Rightarrow n^5 = 5m + r^5 \Rightarrow n^5 - n = 5m - 5q + r^5 - r$$
where $q > 0$, $0 \le r < 5$ and $m$ is some number.

For this to divide by five I need that $5|r^5 - r$, so I iterated over every possible $r$ and checked.

I also managed to prove that $42|n^7 -n$ for every $n$ in the same way.

This process led to some questions:

$1$. Is there a way to shorten this process? I noticed just later that the divisibility by five can easily be proved using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), and I did use some basic modular arithmetics to shorten the calculations, but I still need to go over quite a few numbers.
$2$. How can I prove that a certain number is the g.c.d of a group defined by a polynomial like this? If I have a group $A_k = \{n|\exists m: n = m^k - m \}$ how can I prove that some number $g$ is the g.c.d of the group? Can I generalize this for other polynomials?
$3$. How can I find the g.c.d of such a group?

Comment: $n^5-n=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$ now there are $3$ consecutive numbers hence one of them is divisible by 3 same follows for 2 and for 5  you can see 5k,5k+1,5k-1 give divisibility by 5 easily,and n^2+1 is divisible by 5 otherwise

Comment: Furthermore, in @kingW3's factorization you also have
$$n^2+1=(n^2-4)+5=(n-2)(n+2)+5.$$ So this factor is divisible by five whenever either $n-2$ or $n+2$ is. Putting it all together you see that $n^5-n$ is divisible by five if one of $n-2,n-1,n,n+1,n+2$ is. But that's five consecutive integers.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164524/largest-modulus-for-fermat-type-polynomial.