# Relation between $m,t$ and $q$ in $ k^m\equiv k^{m+t}\pmod{q!}$

Tags: number-theory

Observation

Let $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$

(1)

$$k^m\equiv k^{m+2}\pmod{2!},\ \ m\ge 1$$

(2)

$$k^m\equiv k^{m+2}\pmod{3!}  ,\ \ m\ge 1  $$

(3)

$$k^m\equiv k^{m+2}\pmod{4!}  ,\ \ m\ge 3  $$

(4)

$$k^m\equiv k^{m+4}\pmod{5!} ,\ \ m\ge 3  $$
(5)

$$k^m\equiv k^{m+12}\pmod{6!} ,\ \ m\ge 4  $$

Example: in observation (2)

Choose any $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, now choose any $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$

Let $k=5,m=3\rightarrow 5^3\equiv 5^5\equiv 5^7\equiv 5^9\equiv\cdots \equiv 5^{d} \pmod{3!}$

---

> Question
>
> For equation $ k^m\equiv k^{m+t}\pmod{q!}$
>
> $(1)$ For every $q$ , does there exist $m$ and $t$ which follows above equation?
>
> $(2)$ Can we generalize relation between $m,t$ and  $q$?

Comment: You can use [this simple generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2112671/242) of Fermat &  Euler's theorem.

Comment: What do these congruences mean?  Definitely for a fixed $r$ and $m\ge 1$, $k^m\equiv k^{m+2}\equiv r\pmod{2!}$ does not hold in general (e.g., when $r=1$, $k^m\equiv k^{m+2}\equiv r\pmod{2!}$ is false when $k=0$).

Comment: @WETutorialSchool note $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ and $ r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. $r$ is depends on $k^m$

Comment: Then $r$ is very much irrelevant.  Why didn't you just write $k^m\equiv k^{m+t}\pmod{q!}$?  When you add $r$ into your congruences, it creates a perception that $r$ is arbitrary.

Comment: It can be shown that for every positive integer $n$, the smallest positive integers $m$ and $t$ such that $k^{m}\equiv k^{m+t}\pmod{n}$ for every integer $k$ are the following: $m=\xi(n)$ where $\xi(n) =\max\{s_1,s_1,\ldots,s_l\}$ if $n=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}\cdots p_l^{s_l}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, and $t=\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function.  Any other $m$ and $t$ that work must satisfy $m\ge \xi(n)$ and $\lambda(n)\mid t$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Thank you. You can write it as an answer.

Comment: Oops, I posted the wrong link above. I meant [this Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556393/242). The theorem mentioned by @WETutorialSchool is equivalent to that. If that theorem works for you then we can mark this as a dupe (we already have *many* prior questions that employ that). But if someone want to work out the *specific* details in this case for the factorial modulus then it would not be a dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque  It is almost equivalent to my statement.  The only difference is $\phi(2^k)\ne \lambda(2^k)$ for $k\ge 3$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Correct. There are various versions of these results.

Comment: @BillDubuque  Do you think the smallest degree $d$ such that there exists a monic polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ that satisfies $f(k)\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for all integers $k$ is $d=\xi(n)+\lambda(n)$?  I am not sure how to prove this or whether there is a counterexample.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I vaguely recall seeing various results about such long ago but, alas, I cannot recall the specifics. It would be a useful addition to the site if you post further results about such.

Comment: @BillDubuque  My claim is false.  Let $z(n)$ denote the smallest positive integer $z$ such that $n\mid z!$.  We have $z(n)\le \lambda(n)+1\le \xi(n)+\lambda(n)$.  Then the monic polynomial $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{z(n)}(x-i)$ of degree $z(n)$ satisfies $f(k)\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for every integer $k$.  I don't know if $z(n)$ is the smallest possible degree of such a polynomial $f(x)$, though.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool There is much prior work here. Long ago I had a file of many papers on results in this area but - alas - it was among items that were stolen while in storage. You can locate prior work by searching Zbl / AMS math reviews, perusing Dickson's history, etc. Iirc some also occurred in *Monthly* problems. But it may be quicker to rediscover them in some cases. [Here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82127049.pdf) is one paper I just found with a quick search that yields one entry point into the literature.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool And [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~halorenz/publications/pdf/poly.pdf) is another.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks, theorem 7 of your second paper is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool And another [Stefan Schwarz, The role of semigroups in the elementary theory of numbers. 1981](https://eudml.org/doc/31641)  Chasing citations on those should locate much of the literature on this and related topics.