# What is 333^333^333 in mod 17

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, power-towers

Is there an easier way to do this than finding cycles of different mods? Or can I just first do 333 (mod 17), it gives me 10. Then I could change all the 333's into 10s so it would be 10^10^10 and then do (10^10) first to get a remainder of 2 then 2^10 to get 4 in (mod 17), even though it might be time consuming?

Comment: Is it $333^{(333^{333})}$ or $(333^{333})^{333}$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Exponentiation in Modular Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143052/multiple-exponentiation-in-modular-arithmetic)

Comment: You can't change all of the $333's$ into $10's$, that makes no sense. You can change only the bottom one. For example, $2^2$ and $2^5$ are not congruent mod $3$, even though $2\equiv 5$ (mod $3$). You can't change the power.

Comment: No, you can't.$\,$

Comment: @JohnOmielan This is not really a duplicate. Bill Dubuque, aka the King of Duplicates, will be angry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although $333\equiv10\bmod17$, it is not true that $333^{{333}^{333}}\equiv10^{{10}^{10}}\bmod17$.

Generally, $a\equiv b\bmod n$ does not imply that $c^a\equiv c^b\bmod n$.

Rather, $a\equiv b\bmod \phi(n)$ and $\gcd(c,n)=1$ implies $c^a\equiv c^b\bmod n$,

where $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function):  $\phi(17)=16$ and $\phi(16)=8$.

Now $333\equiv13\bmod16$ and $333\equiv5\bmod8$, so $333^{333}\equiv13^5\bmod16$.

To reduce further, it helps to note that $13^4\equiv(-3)^4=81
\equiv1\bmod16$,

so $13^5\equiv13\bmod16$.  Therefore, $333^{{333}^{333}}\equiv10^{{13}}\bmod17$.

Can you take it from here?