# What happens to $n^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1$ when $n$ and $p$ are not co-prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, coprime

We know $n^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1$ in the case $n$ and $p$ are co-prime i.e. $ gcd(n,p) = 1$. What is the case when they are not co-prime? What happens to $n^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1$?

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: congruent modulo what?

Comment: [Carmichael Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner modulo $p$.

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $n$ and $p$ are not co-prime, then $n \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Comment: Even, if $p$ is not prime, if $n$ and $p$ are not coprime, there is a prime number $q$ dividing both $n$ and $p$ , then $n^k\equiv 1\mod p$ (with $k\ge 1$) would imply $n^k\equiv 1\mod q$ , hence $q\mid n^k-1$ which contradicts to $q\mid n$. So, the congruence cannot be satisfied when $n$ and $p$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 0):

It is false:  $\,n^{\phi}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}n^{\phi}+k\,\color{#c00}p = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(\color{#c00}{n,p}) = 1,\,$ by $\,\phi \ge 1$

But there do exist such generalizations of the other form of Fermat $\,a^{p}\equiv a\pmod{\!p}\,$ such as below.

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose  $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose for all $\,i,\,$  $\ e\ge e_i\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{i}})\mid f.\ $ Then $\ m\mid a^e(a^f-1)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z,\,$ i.e. $$\qquad\qquad a^{\large e+f}\equiv a^{\large e}\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\quad {\rm for\ all}\ \ a\in\Bbb Z$$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3052342/242) for proofs and examples.