# Number of $k^{th}$ root modulo m

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question is about the number of $k^{th}$ root modulo *m*. Consider the congruence equation $$x^k\equiv b\pmod m \tag {$\clubsuit$}$$


I want to ask two questions:

(a) Prove that if $\gcd(b, m) = 1$ and $\gcd(k, \varphi(m)) = 1$, there is exactly one $k^{th}$ root modulo *m* to ($\clubsuit$)

(b) If $\gcd(k, \varphi(m)) > 1$, {$\clubsuit$} has no $k^{th}$ root modulo *m* or it has at least two $k^{th}$ roots modulo *m*.


For (a), I can prove the result if the $k^{th}$ root modulo *m* is relatively prime to *m* or *m* is a product of distinct primes with the idea from [Finding the $k^{th}$ root modulo m](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073284/finding-the-kth-root-modulo-m).


For (b), I have no idea what to do.

Comment: For part (a) you're already there: if $\gcd(x,m)\neq1$ then you must have $\gcd(b,m)\neq1$; can you see why?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see, it is because $b = qm + x^k$ for some integer *q* and hence $gcd(x, m)$ divides *b*. Then $gcd(b, m) \ge gcd(x,m)$. So, we must have $gcd(x, m) = 1$. And now I can prove (a), THX!

Comment: If $gcd(k,\phi(n))=d>1$ can we say that, the given congruence has either no solution or $d$ incongruent solutions.