# Let $b, k$, and $n$ be integers that satisfy $\gcd(b, n) = 1$ and $\gcd(k, \varphi(n)) = 1$. Show that $b$ has exactly one kth root modulo $n$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $b, k,$ and $n$ be integers that satisfy $\gcd(b, n) = 1$ and $\gcd(k, φ(n)) = 1$.
Show that $b$ has exactly one $k^{\text{th}}$ root modulo $n$.

Comment: See the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495058/number-of-kth-root-modulo-m?noredirect=1&lq=1), part (a). The answer is in the comments and the duplicate link.

Comment: Eh, I am still stuck on where to start.